# Should I be writing logs to console in production?

Tags: node.js, logging, standards, winston

I'm using node js and`winston` logger.

I log `info`, `warn` and `error` levels to a file as well as console.
Additionally, I'm also logging some `debug` and `silly` level logs to the console

I wanted to keep my own log file, as well as keep the logs in `journalctl`.

However, I have a few concerns:

1. Does it affect my performace? (As I/O is involved)
2. Is it the right thing to do? (didnt help Ned Stark anyway)
3. Should I be avoiding logging to console in production and keep console clean?

Comment: 1) of course 2) not for us to decide 3) not for us to decide

Comment: Winston loggin is done asynchronously. Nevertheless, it may have an adverse effect on speed when loggin to console. As @TimCastelijns said, question#2 and question#3 are subjective. In case you decide to keep both console and file logs, you can shift to faster loggers. Recently I was trying [Pino](https://github.com/pinojs/pino#benchmarks). It is quite faster than Winston.

Comment: @TimCastelijns I'm asking about standards here. What is the general thing people do?

Comment: Doing something because others do it is not how you should make decisions for your own application

Comment: @TimCastelijns I dont think so. Conventions and best practices should always at least be regarded when making design decisions like this one. They cannot/should not be discussed in SO however, of course